# The snake lemma and a proof of the Jordan-Hölder theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof of Jordan-Hölder theorem given in Poonen's [handout](http://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/704/jordan-holder.pdf)
which for convenience I partly reproduce here:

**Jordan–Hölder theorem**. Let $G$ be a group. Every Jordan–Hölder filtration of $G$ has the
same multiset ${gr_i (G)}$ of composition factors.

**Proof:** We may assume $G \neq 1,$ and that G has a Jordan–Hölder filtration; let $l(G)$ denotethe length of a shortest one. We use induction on $l(G)$.

*Base case:* $l(G) = 1$. Then the only Jordan–Hölder filtration is $1 \subset G.$

*Inductive step:* Suppose that $l(G) ≥ 2.$ Let $N$ be the group just below $G$ in a shortest
Jordan–Hölder filtration. Thus $N \subset G,$ and $l(N)$ and $l(G/N)$ are strictly less than $l(G).$
Let $(G_i)$ be any Jordan–Hölder filtration of $G.$ It induces filtrations on $N$ and $G/N$
namely, $N_i := G_i ∩ N$ and $(G/N)_i := im(G_i → G/N).$ The exact sequence
$1 → N → G → G/N → 1$
induces an exact sequence $1 → N_i → G_i → (G/N )_i → 1.$

Applying the snake lemma to

[image]

yields an exact sequence
$1 → gr_i(N ) → gr_i (G) → gr_i (G/N ) → 1.$
Since $gr_i(G)$ is simple, one of $gr_i (N )$ and $gr_i (G/N )$ is 1 and the other is isomorphic to $gr_i (G).$
In particular, $(N_i)$ with duplicates removed is a Jordan–Hölder filtration of $N$ , and likewise
for $((G/N )_i)$ and $G/N$ , and
${gr_i (G)} = {gr_i (N )} \sqcup {gr_i (G/N )}$
as multisets, where it is understood that on the right we discard all quotients isomorphic
to 1. By the inductive hypothesis, ${gr_i (N )}$ and ${gr_i (G/N )}$ are each independent of the
choice of filtration $(G_i )$, so ${gr_i(G)}$ is too.

**Questions:** I think I understand the first part, inducing those first exact sequences essentially amounts to the [correspondence theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)) I also understand the conclusion given that exact sequence of the composition factors. What I don't understand is the step where the snake lemma came in. Why does the snake lemma even hold at all here?

Comment: Rather than using the Snake Lemma, I prefer the proof using the Butterfly Lemma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using inclusion maps between $(N_{i+1},N_i)$,$(G_{i+1},G_i)$, $((G/N)_{i+1},(G/N)_i)$, Snake's lemma is used to get the exact sequence:
$1 \rightarrow N_i/N_{i+1} \rightarrow G_i/G_{i+1} \rightarrow (G/N)_i/(G/N)_{i+1} \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: But the groups aren't abelian, so how does the snake lemma apply?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53124/snake-lemma-in-category-of-groups